# What do I have to do to make my WH_SHELL or WH_CBT hook procedure receive events from other processes?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, hook

I'm trying to use `SetWindowsHookEx` to set up a `WH_SHELL` hook to get notified of system-wide `HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED` and `HSHELL_WINDOWDESTROYED` events. I pass 0 for the final `dwThreadId` argument which, according to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx), should "associate the hook procedure with all existing threads running in the same desktop as the calling thread". I also pass in the handle to my DLL (`HInstance` in Delphi) for the `hMod` parameter as did all the examples I looked at.

Yet, I only ever get notified of windows created by my own app and - more often than not - my tests result in the desktop process going down in flames once I close down my app. Before you ask, I do call `UnhookWindowsHookEx`. I also always call `CallNextHookEx` from within my handler.

I am running my test app from a limited user account but so far I haven't found any hints indicating that this would play a role... (though that actually surprises me)

AFAICT, I did everything by the book (obviously I didn't but so far I fail to see where).

I'm using Delphi (2007) but that shouldn't really matter I think.

**EDIT:** Maybe I should have mentioned this before: I did download and try a couple of examples (though there are unfortunately not that many available for Delphi - especially none for `WH_SHELL` or `WH_CBT`). While they do not crash the system like my test app does, they still do not capture events from other processes (even though I can verify with ProcessExplorer that they get loaded into them alright). So it seems there is either something wrong with my system configuration or the examples are wrong or it is simply not possible to capture events from other processes. Can anyone enlighten me?

**EDIT2:** OK, here's the source of my test project.

The DLL containing the hook procedure:

```
library HookHelper;

uses
  Windows;

{$R *.res}

type
  THookCallback = procedure(ACode, AWParam, ALParam: Integer); stdcall;

var
  WndHookCallback: THookCallback;
  Hook: HHook;

function HookProc(ACode, AWParam, ALParam: Integer): Integer; stdcall;
begin
  Result := CallNextHookEx(Hook, ACode, AWParam, ALParam);
  if ACode < 0 then Exit;
  try
    if Assigned(WndHookCallback)
//    and (ACode in [HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED, HSHELL_WINDOWDESTROYED]) then
    and (ACode in [HCBT_CREATEWND, HCBT_DESTROYWND]) then
      WndHookCallback(ACode, AWParam, ALParam);
  except
    // plop!
  end;
end;

procedure InitHook(ACallback: THookCallback); register;
begin
//  Hook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_SHELL, @HookProc, HInstance, 0);
  Hook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, @HookProc, HInstance, 0);
  if Hook = 0 then
    begin
//      ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
    end
  else
    begin
      WndHookCallback := ACallback;
    end;
end;

procedure UninitHook; register;
begin
  if Hook <> 0 then
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(Hook);
  WndHookCallback := nil;
end;

exports
  InitHook,
  UninitHook;

begin
end.
```

And the main form of the app using the hook:

```
unit MainFo;

interface

uses
  Windows, SysUtils, Forms, Dialogs, Classes, Controls, Buttons, StdCtrls;

type
  THookTest_Fo = class(TForm)
    Hook_Btn: TSpeedButton;
    Output_Lbx: TListBox;
    Test_Btn: TButton;
    procedure Hook_BtnClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Test_BtnClick(Sender: TObject);
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  HookTest_Fo: THookTest_Fo;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

type
  THookCallback = procedure(ACode, AWParam, ALParam: Integer); stdcall;

procedure InitHook(const ACallback: THookCallback); register; external 'HookHelper.dll';
procedure UninitHook; register; external 'HookHelper.dll';

procedure HookCallback(ACode, AWParam, ALParam: Integer); stdcall;
begin
  if Assigned(HookTest_Fo) then
    case ACode of
  //    HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED:
      HCBT_CREATEWND:
          HookTest_Fo.Output_Lbx.Items.Add('created handle #' + IntToStr(AWParam));
  //    HSHELL_WINDOWDESTROYED:
      HCBT_DESTROYWND:
        HookTest_Fo.Output_Lbx.Items.Add('destroyed handle #' + IntToStr(AWParam));
    else
      HookTest_Fo.Output_Lbx.Items.Add(Format('code: %d, WParam: $%x, LParam: $%x', [ACode, AWParam, ALParam]));
    end;
end;

procedure THookTest_Fo.Test_BtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Boo!');
end;

destructor THookTest_Fo.Destroy;
begin
  UninitHook; // just to make sure
  inherited;
end;

procedure THookTest_Fo.Hook_BtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Hook_Btn.Down then
    InitHook(HookCallback)
  else
    UninitHook;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that your hook DLL is actually being loaded into several different address spaces. Any time Windows detects an event in some foreign process that must be processed by your hook, it loads the hook DLL into that process (if it's not already loaded, of course).

However, each process has its own address space. This means that the callback function pointer that you passed in InitHook() only makes sense in the context of your EXE (that's why it works for events in your app). In any other process that pointer is **garbage**; it may point to an invalid memory location or (worse) into some random code section. The result can either be an access violation or silent memory corruption.

Generally, the solution is to use some sort of [interprocess communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574(VS.85).aspx) (IPC) to properly notify your EXE. The most painless way for your case would be to post a message and cram the needed info (event and HWND) into its WPARAM/LPARAM. You could either use a WM_APP+n or create one with RegisterWindowMessage(). Make sure the message is posted and not sent, to avoid any deadlocks.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds really promising. I'll try that on Monday.

Comment: Yep, works perfectly now. Thanks again, also for the very good explanation of why my approach didn't work.

Comment: @Oliver Could you expand further on which communication you have chosen?

Comment: @NGLN : I chose the message-based approach. Instead of a pointer to the callback I'm now passing the handle of my message receiver to `InitHook`.

Answer (score 2):

This might be tertiary to your question, but as you're seeing, hooks are **very** hard to get right - if you can avoid using this by any means, do it. You're going to run into all sorts of problems with them, especially on Vista where you'll have to deal with UIPI.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify something that "efotinis" mentioned about posting messages back to your process - the wParam and lParam  that you post to your main process can't be pointers, they can just be "numbers".

For example, lets say you hook the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING message, windows passes you a pointer to a WINDOWPOS in the lparam. You can't just post that lparam back to your main process because the memory the lparam is pointing to is only valid in the process that recieves the message.

This is what "efotinis" meant when he said " cram the needed info (event and HWND) into its WPARAM/LPARAM". If you want to pass more complex messages back your going to need to use some other IPC (like named pipes, TCP or memory mapped files).

Answer (score 0):

Lol, it looks like the error is in the test code.

If you create two separate buttons, one for Init and one for UnInit (I prefer Exit).

```
procedure THooktest_FO.UnInitClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UninitHook;
end;

procedure THooktest_FO.InitClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  InitHook(HookCallback)
end;
```

Start the app. Click Init and then The test button, the following output is shown:

```
created handle #1902442
destroyed handle #1902442
created handle #1967978
created handle #7276488
```

Then the messagebox is shown.

If you click ok you get:

```
destroyed handle #1967978
```

HTH

Comment: Yes, I get the same output. The button is a TSpeedButton with AllowAllUp = True. My problem is that I do not get any notifications about other processes, i.e. when I open or close other applications.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Delphi base documentation for SetWindowsHookEx. But the text is a bit vague.

```
function SetWindowsHookEx(idHook: Integer; lpfn: TFNHookProc; 
  hmod: HInst; dwThreadId: DWORD): HHOOK;
```

- hmod: A handle to the module (a DLL) containing the hook function pointed to by the lpfn parameter. This parameter must be set to zero if dwThreadId identifies a thread created by the current process an dlpfn points to a hook function located in the code associated with the current process.
- dwThreadId: The identifier of the thread to which the installed hook function will be associated. If this parameter is set to zero, the hook will be a system-wide hook that is associated with all existing threads.

By the way, for the hmod parameter you should have used a module handle. (HINSTANCE points to the application handle).

```
hand := GetModuleHandle('hookhelper.dll');
Hook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_SHELL, @HookProc, hand, 0);
```

But although hand differs from HINSTANCE it still shows the same result.

Comment: I grabbed the HInstance straight from the samples (e.g. on About.com). And it does not always point to the application. In DLLs it points to the DLL itself. That's for instance why you can use it in TBitmap.LoadFromResourceName et al. from inside DLLs.

Comment: I checked the values, but both HInstance in the DLL and in the App are the same. But it still won't help so we need more info ;-) (fortunately I like puzzles like this)