# WH_SHELL Hook do not recognize other processes' messages on Windows 8

Tags: delphi, winapi, hook

I'm trying to notice, when OneNote is opened or set to foreground. So I searched my old source files and found the DLLs for Hooks, which did their job on Win XP. 
But awefully, they do not on windows 8. I do get Messages from my own Application including Buttons and Textfields, but no other Application triggers the callback function :-(
Running the Hook-starting Exe as Administrator, doesn't change the issue.

```
var
HookHandle: Cardinal = 0;
WindowHandle : Cardinal = 0;

function HookProc(nCode: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM):
LRESULT; stdcall;
var s:PChar;
begin
Result := CallNextHookEx(HookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);

// debug if the callback function is triggerd...
SendMessage(WindowHandle,WM_USER+999,wParam,lParam);
case nCode < 0 of
TRUE: exit;
FALSE:
begin

  if nCode=HSHELL_WINDOWCREATED then begin
     SendMessage(WindowHandle,WM_USER+999,wParam,lParam);
    GetMem(s,GetWindowTextLength(wParam)+2);
    GetWindowText(wParam,s,GetWindowTextLength(wParam)+2);
    //if (AnsiEndsStr('OneNote',s)) then begin
    CallNextHookEx(HookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
  end;
end;
end;
end;

function InstallHook(Hwnd: Cardinal): Boolean; stdcall;
begin
Result := False;
if HookHandle = 0 then begin
HookHandle := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_SHELL, @HookProc, HInstance, 0);
WindowHandle := Hwnd;
Result := TRUE;
end;
end;

function UninstallHook: Boolean; stdcall;
begin
Result := UnhookWindowsHookEx(HookHandle);
HookHandle := 0;
end;

exports
InstallHook,
UninstallHook;
end.
```

Comment: finally understood the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299370/what-do-i-have-to-do-to-make-my-wh-shell-or-wh-cbt-hook-procedure-receive-events?rq=1
Instead of 
    SendMessage(WindowHandle,WM_USER+999,wParam,lParam);
I use 
    SendMessage(FindWindow(nil,'Form1'),WM_USER+999,wParam,lParam);
now.
But I'm still not getting all of the created Windows...
Could this be the 32-Bit and 64-Bit Problem with Hooks? How can I recognize, wether a Application ist 64-Bit or not?

Comment: The code looks very sketchy indeed. HWND is not Cardinal. Code is broken under x64. No error checking. You call CallNextHookEx twice. The +2 looks very odd indeed. You leak memory. FWIW, it is far easier to use RegisterShellHookWindow. I suggest that instead of copying very poorly written code without understanding it, that you read the MSDN docs and write the code correctly. But definitely prefer RegisterShellHookWindow to a hook.